# Change attributes use_flash true/false with button

Tags: android, android-layout, barcode-scanner

i made barcode scaner with barcodereader. Flash active on the layout can be used well...

But with button onclick, I do not understand using it ...
is there anything that can help ??

Layout Scanner :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.material.components.activity.ScanLogin">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:name="info.androidhive.barcode.BarcodeReader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:auto_focus="true"
        app:use_flash="false" />

    <info.androidhive.barcode.ScannerOverlay
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
        app:line_color="@color/global_color_green_primary"
        app:line_speed="6"
        app:line_width="4"
        app:square_height="200"
        app:square_width="200" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_off" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity Scanner :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_scan);

        barcodeReader = (BarcodeReader) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_scanner);

        btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

        toggleButtonImage();

        btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    ledoff();
                } else {
                    ledon();
                }
            }
        });
    }

void ledon() {
        isFlashOn = true;
        playSound();
        toggleButtonImage();
        framescan.setTag(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    }

    void ledoff() {
        isFlashOn = false;
        playSound();
        toggleButtonImage();
        framescan.setTag(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }
```

toglebutton serves to change the condition of the button to be on/off.
playsound works to play sound ... no problem with toglebutton and playsound. promlem in function use_flash.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void getCamera() {
if (camera == null) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        params = camera.getParameters();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}}

private void turnOffFlash() {
if (isFlashOn) {
    if (camera == null || params == null) {
        return;
    }
    // play sound


    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.stopPreview();
    isFlashOn = false;

    // changing button/switch image
    toggleButtonImage();
}}

private void turnOnFlash() {
if (!isFlashOn) {
    if (camera == null || params == null) {
        return;
    }
    // play sound
    playSound();

    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
    isFlashOn = true;

    // changing button/switch image
    toggleButtonImage();
}}
```

This code will help to achieve your requirements.And not forget to ask for the permission for the camera.

Comment: can you show me the current code what you have changed ? so that i can tell you what was going wrong in that